# Is there any way to avoid annotations from flickering in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I'm polishing my app and want to avoid flickering of annotations. Is there any way to fix this?

Currently I delete old annotation right after the new one was created like so

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {

        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = locations.last!.coordinate

        annotation.title = "Speed"
        let speed = locations.last!.speed * 3.6 // converting to km/h
        annotation.subtitle = String(format: "%.2f km/h", speed)

        self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

        if let oldAnnotation = self.drawer.oldAnnotation {

            self.mapView.removeAnnotation(oldAnnotation)

        }
        self.mapView.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated: false)

        self.drawer.oldAnnotation = annotation
}
```

[image: flickering]

Comment: I would think this constant process of adding, deleting, and reading your annotation's are causing this jittery appearance. I would try to just update the position of one annotation, which should give a much more fluid motion

Comment: Well, that helps, but brokes my rotating pattern. on every annotation I create a rotated arrow. How should I add arrow with an angle then? In :didAdd views: map delegate?

Comment: You're using Apple's MapKit, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right